# Where is the OTHER Wesnoth data stored?

Tags: software-center

I had installed The Battle for Wesnoth (latest version) from the Ubuntu Software Centre on my Ubuntu Utopic Unicorn (U3!). I then uninstalled it for a while. Later I installed it again.

To my surprise, despite deleting (using a terminal) '~/.local/share/wesnoth' I found my save files automatically present when I reinstalled! I have uninstalled it again and found that the folder was back.

This time I have removed the same folder ('~/.local/wesnoth') and can't find any folder '.wesnoth' (maybe I removed that one too.)

Is there some folder I am not aware of that stores a copy of my save files? I'd like to keep my disk squeaky clean.

P.S. I have run,

> sudo apt-get autoclean

(Not that it will make a difference seeing Wesnoth was installed from the Software Centre.)

Comment: Try using this on the Terminal: `cd $HOME; find . -type d -name "*wesnoth*"`  See if it gives you any directories that have 'wesnoth' in the name.